# i have 3 screens when i get back to my first screen its broken,black Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, screen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0Wri.jpg
there is a video and here is my full code of these screens:

there is a video and here is my full code of these screens:

there is a video and here is my full code of these screens:

there is a video and here is my full code of these screens:

there is a video and here is my full code of these screens:

Screen one:

```
class AccountPage extends StatelessWidget {
  late AppController appController;

  AccountPage(appController){
    this.appController = appController;
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10),
          height: this.appController.queryData.size.height * (2/30),
          child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.accsett,
            style: TextStyle(color: this.appController.themeController.thirdAppDeepColor,
                fontSize: 26 * this.appController.fontSizeFactorBasedOnOs * (this.appController.queryData.size.height/1000)),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 1,
          color: this.appController.themeController.appGreyColor,
        ),
        this.appController.loggedIn ?
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
          height: this.appController.queryData.size.height * (1.5/30),
          child: ElevatedButton(
              child:
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.profile,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          fontSize: 24 * this.appController.fontSizeFactorBasedOnOs * (this.appController.queryData.size.height/1000)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                elevation: this.appController.themeController.evTransparentButtonElevation as MaterialStateProperty<double?>,
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                    side: BorderSide.none,
                  ),
                ),
                padding: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<EdgeInsets>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5);
                  },
                ),
                foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return this.appController.themeController.thirdAppDeepColor;
                  },
                ),
                overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return this.appController.themeController.secondAppLightColor;
                  },
                ),
                shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return Colors.transparent;
                  },
                ),
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return Colors.transparent;
                  },
                ),

              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new ProfilePage(appController)),
                );
              },
            )
        )
            :
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, top:10 ),
          height: this.appController.queryData.size.height * (2/30),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.please,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    fontSize: 24 * this.appController.fontSizeFactorBasedOnOs * (this.appController.queryData.size.height/1000),
                    color: this.appController.themeController.thirdAppDeepColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  height: this.appController.queryData.size.height * (2/30),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    child:
                    Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.login),
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                          child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.login,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                fontSize: 24 * this.appController.fontSizeFactorBasedOnOs * (this.appController.queryData.size.height/1000)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          side: BorderSide.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                      padding: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<EdgeInsets>(
                            (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                          return EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5);
                        },
                      ),
                      foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                            (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                          if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed))
                            return this.appController.themeController.thirdAppDeepColor;
                          else
                            return this.appController.themeController.appWhiteDeepColor;
                        },
                      ),
                      overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                            (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                          return this.appController.themeController.secondAppLightColor;
                        },
                      ),
                      shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                            (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                          return Colors.transparent;
                        },
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                            (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                          return this.appController.themeController.thirdAppDeepColor;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      this.appController.logOut(context);
                    },
                  )
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
                :
            Container()
        )
            :
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, top:10 ),
          height: this.appController.queryData.size.height * (2/30),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.to_use_acc_sett,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    fontSize: 24 * this.appController.fontSizeFactorBasedOnOs * (this.appController.queryData.size.height/1000),
                    color: this.appController.themeController.thirdAppDeepColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        (this.appController.loggedIn  && appController.userContract != null) ?
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
          height: this.appController.queryData.size.height * (1.5/30),
          child: ElevatedButton(
              child:
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.fact_check),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.bookings,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          fontSize: 24 * this.appController.fontSizeFactorBasedOnOs * (this.appController.queryData.size.height/1000)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                elevation: this.appController.themeController.evTransparentButtonElevation as MaterialStateProperty<double?>,
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                    side: BorderSide.none,
                  ),
                ),
                padding: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<EdgeInsets>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5);
                  },
                ),
                foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return this.appController.themeController.thirdAppDeepColor;
                  },
                ),
                overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return this.appController.themeController.secondAppLightColor;
                  },
                ),
                shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return Colors.transparent;
                  },
                ),
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return Colors.transparent;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new ShowBookingsPage(appController)),
                );
              },
            )
        )
            :
        Container(),
        this.appController.loggedIn ?
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
          height: this.appController.queryData.size.height * (1.5/30),
          child: ElevatedButton(
              child:
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.electrical_services),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.sessions,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          fontSize: 24 * this.appController.fontSizeFactorBasedOnOs * (this.appController.queryData.size.height/1000)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                elevation: this.appController.themeController.evTransparentButtonElevation as MaterialStateProperty<double?>,
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                    side: BorderSide.none,
                  ),
                ),
                padding: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<EdgeInsets>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5);
                  },
                ),
                foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return this.appController.themeController.thirdAppDeepColor;
                  },
                ),
                overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return this.appController.themeController.secondAppLightColor;
                  },
                ),
                shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return Colors.transparent;
                  },
                ),
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return Colors.transparent;
                  },
                ),

              ),
              onPressed: () {
                **Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new ShowSessionsPage(appController)),
                );**
              },
            )
        )
            :
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10),
          height: this.appController.queryData.size.height * (2/30),
          child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.accsett,
            style: TextStyle(color: this.appController.themeController.thirdAppDeepColor,
                fontSize: 26 * this.appController.fontSizeFactorBasedOnOs * (this.appController.queryData.size.height/1000)),
          ),
        ),

        (this.appController.loggedIn  && appController.userContract != null) ?
        Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
            height: this.appController.queryData.size.height * (1.5/30),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child:
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    child: Text('MyBill',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          fontSize: 24 * this.appController.fontSizeFactorBasedOnOs * (this.appController.queryData.size.height/1000)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                elevation: this.appController.themeController.evTransparentButtonElevation as MaterialStateProperty<double?>,
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                    side: BorderSide.none,
                  ),
                ),
                padding: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<EdgeInsets>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5);
                  },
                ),
                foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return this.appController.themeController.thirdAppDeepColor;
                  },
                ),
                overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return this.appController.themeController.secondAppLightColor;
                  },
                ),
                shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return Colors.transparent;
                  },
                ),
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return Colors.transparent;
                  },
                ),

              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new MyBillPage(appController)),
                );
              },
            )
        ):
        Container(),
 
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10),
          height: this.appController.queryData.size.height * (2/30),
          child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.app_sett,
            style: TextStyle(color: this.appController.themeController.thirdAppDeepColor,
                fontSize: 26 * this.appController.fontSizeFactorBasedOnOs * (this.appController.queryData.size.height/1000)),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 1,
          color: this.appController.themeController.appGreyColor,
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
          height: this.appController.queryData.size.height * (1.5/30),
          child: ElevatedButton(
              child:
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.settings),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.settings,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          fontSize: 24 * this.appController.fontSizeFactorBasedOnOs * (this.appController.queryData.size.height/1000)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                elevation: this.appController.themeController.evTransparentButtonElevation as MaterialStateProperty<double?>,
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                    side: BorderSide.none,
                  ),
                ),
                padding: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<EdgeInsets>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5);
                  },
                ),
                foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return this.appController.themeController.thirdAppDeepColor;
                  },
                ),
                overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return this.appController.themeController.secondAppLightColor;
                  },
                ),
                shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return Colors.transparent;
                  },
                ),
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                    return Colors.transparent;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            )
        ),
            :
        Container(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Screen two:

```
class ShowSessionsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  late final AppController appController;

  ShowSessionsPage(appController) {
    this.appController = appController;
  }

  _ShowSessionsPageState createState() => _ShowSessionsPageState();
}

class _ShowSessionsPageState extends State<ShowSessionsPage>{
  List<SessionOrBookingPanel> sessionPanels = [];
  bool sessionsLoaded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadSessions();
  }

  void loadSessions() async {
    if (await widget.appController.fetchChargeTransactions())
      setState(() {
        sessionsLoaded = true;
      });
  }

  void createSessionPanels(List<dynamic> sessions) {
    int i = 0;
    sessionPanels.clear();
    if (sessions.length != 0){
      while (i < sessions.length){
        sessionPanels.add(new SessionOrBookingPanel(sessions[i], widget.appController, true, true));
        i++;
      }
    }
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    createSessionPanels(widget.appController.sessions);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        leading: IconButton(
          color: widget.appController.themeController.appBlackDeepColor,
          tooltip: 'Back',
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          icon: (widget.appController.deviceIsAndroid) ? const Icon(Icons.arrow_back) : const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  AccountPage(widget.appController)),
            );
          },
        ),
        title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.sessions,
          style: TextStyle(color: widget.appController.themeController.appBlackDeepColor),),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: sessionsLoaded ?
      Column(
        children: [ ElevatedButton(child: Text('Open Callendar'),
            onPressed: () => {Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Calendar(widget.appController)),
            )}),
          Expanded(
            flex: 15,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
              child: ListView.separated(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) => sessionPanels[index],
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(color: Colors.transparent,),
                  itemCount: sessionPanels.length),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
          :
      Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Screen three:

```
class Calendar extends StatelessWidget {
  late AppController appController;
  Calendar(appController){
    this.appController = appController;
  }  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
      supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
      
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(appController),
    );
  }

}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  late AppController appController;
  MyHomePage(appController){
    this.appController = appController;
  }

 


  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DateRangePickerController _datePickerController = DateRangePickerController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(widget.appController.list);
    return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title:Text('My Calendar'),
            leading: IconButton(
              color: widget.appController.themeController.appWhiteLightColor,
              tooltip: 'Back',
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              icon: (widget.appController.deviceIsAndroid) ? const Icon(Icons.arrow_back) : const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  ShowSessionsPage(widget.appController)),
              );
              },
            ),
          ),
          body: SfDateRangePicker(
            navigationDirection: DateRangePickerNavigationDirection.vertical,
            navigationMode: DateRangePickerNavigationMode.scroll,
            view: DateRangePickerView.month,
            monthViewSettings: DateRangePickerMonthViewSettings(firstDayOfWeek: 6,
            specialDates:widget.appController.specialDates),
            monthCellStyle: DateRangePickerMonthCellStyle(
              specialDatesDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xFF2B732F), width: 1),
                  shape: BoxShape.circle),
              blackoutDateTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
              specialDatesTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.multiple,
            onSelectionChanged: _onSelectionChanged,
            controller: _datePickerController,
            onCancel: () {
              _datePickerController.selectedRanges = null;
            },
          ),
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: In ScreenOne you are not using a Scaffold.

Comment: yeah this black color got away with scaffold but still its not on the right position and bottomnavigationbar still not showing

Comment: Because the AppBar disappeared due to some condition is broken in Screen One.

Comment: there is no appbar in screen one

Comment: is this unwrapping `AppLocalizations.of(context)!.accsett` throwing some exception?

Answer (score 1):

As I see it isn't broken, you aren't wrapping it with a `Scaffold` Widget.
The problem here, at first you are using `Account Page` as a child of `BottomNavigationBar` Widget, so it takes its parent from it, but the second time you are navigating to it as a separate page and here it doesn't have a `Scaffold` Widget as a parent, so it isn't styled / organized.

- All you need to do is to navigate to it as a child of the `BottomNavigationBar` Widget by only changing the index of it, like this:

> `set State ((){ _currentIndex = newIndex;});`

or using a state management such as: (Provider - Riverpod - Get-x - Bloc....etc).

hope I could help.

Comment: what should i change? can you write the code?

Comment: actually it's hard to indicate because I don't know the way you are using it, but you should navigate by changing "currentIndex"